# why does pd.drop not function the same outside a for-loop as it does inside a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

On a single dataframe, I can drop columns using the conventional `df = df.drop('column name')`. But when I try to loop over multiple dataframes and apply `drop()` to each one, the changes are not persistent. I know there is an `inplace='True'` argument that I can use but I am confused by what is fundamentally going on inside the for loop.

Example:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6]})
df_1
    A   B
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20,30], 'C':[40,50,60]})
df_2
     A   C
0   10  40
1   20  50
2   30  60

# this is the behavior I am looking for. 
df_1 = df_1.drop('A', axis=1)
df_1


    B
0   4
1   5
2   6

# when I put 2 dataframes in a for loop, I do not get the same output. 
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20,30], 'C':[40,50,60]})
full_data = [df_1, df_2]

# I expect this code to apply the "drop" for each of these dataframes in the same way 
# as above without the need for the "inplace" argument.
for dataset in full_data:
    dataset = dataset.drop('A', axis=1)

# the column 'A' should have been dropped for each dataframe while inside the loop 
# but it wasnt. why?
df_1
    A   B
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue doesn't have to do with loop scoping specifically, but is a basic python assignment rules issue. See the following:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})

In [3]: another = df

In [4]: another is df
Out[4]: True

In [5]: another = another.drop('A', axis=1)

In [6]: another is df
Out[6]: False
```

In this example, you can see that assigning the result of the drop operation to `another` assignes a new object to the identifier `another`. It does not modify the `df` object in-place. On the other hand, using the `inplace=True` keyword does:

```py
In [7]: another = df

In [8]: another.drop('A', axis=1, inplace=True)

In [9]: another is df
Out[9]: True
```

Essentially, there is no way to do what you are trying to do, which is to loop over a list of objects and then modify the object contents in place by re-assigning to the variables using the loop identifier. The reason the `inplace=True` argument works is because it is referencing a method on the dataframe itself, giving pandas control over the assignment of the result.

Check out this article on [variables and object references](https://realpython.com/python-variables/#object-references) or more info.

Answer (score 3):

By doing `dataset = dataset.drop('A', axis=1)` in your loop, you are just assigning the variable in the loop. If you add `print(dataset)` you will see Column A dropped.

Try `dataset.drop(columns=['A'], axis=1, inplace=True)` in your loop instead.

```py
for dataset in [df_1, df_2]:
    dataset.drop('A', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The object you are changing has to be defined outside of loop or else its scope is local to that for loop. This example uses a predefined list to solve the issue:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20,30], 'C':[40,50,60]})
l=[]

for dataset in [df_1, df_2]:
    l.append(dataset.drop("A", axis=1))

df_1=l[0]
df_2=l[1]
```